# PlUpload not resizing my images

Tags: plupload

I am a bit baffled by the fact that I can't seem to have PlUpload working properly. I need to have client image resizing. I upgraded it recently to the latest version.

Files are transmitted and handled correctly, it's just the resizing that doesn't work. It is not giving any errors. My config goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/i18n/it.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
```

And then

```
  $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,flash',
    url : '/uploadsample',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',

    resize : { width : 1024, height : 1024, quality : 80 },

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
      {extensions : 'gif'} ,{extensions : 'png'} ,{extensions : 'jpg'}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '/js/Moxie.swf'
  });
```

I am using html5 runtime and I tried in Chrome and Firefox, Ubuntu.
I am trying with small images, about 1600 px at most (I am aware of the 6500+ pixel limit, but I am not hitting this limit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch. It was a bug in version 2.1.4. Version 2.1.7 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue like this,

I have added a attribute to resize parameter that is:

```
resize : { width : 1024, height : 1024, quality : 80,enabled:true },
```